# In HTML5 canvas, how can I change the stroke alpha without affecting the shadow color alpha?

Tags: canvas, shadow

I'm trying to draw an inner shadow following [the example found here](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/april/an-example-of-html5-canvas-shadows.html).  I'm trying to modify it a bit so that the stroke is fully transparent, e.g.:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)';
```

However, this is causing my shadow alpha to become 0.0 as well, despite the fact that I have this line defined as well:

```
ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)';
```

Is there a way that I can force the shadow's alpha to stay at 1.0 despite the stroke style being at 0.0?  I don't want the stroke to be shown, I just want the shadow to be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to offset the shape so that the shape is outside the canvas and the shadow inside.

This way we don't need to consider the original shape's color - or - we can duplicate the path and draw on top later if we want it to be partly transparent.

For example:

```
var offset = 1000;

/// to keep original points of shape we just translate
ctx.translate(-offset, 0);

/// create some shape, here a line
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
ctx.lineTo(400, 300);
ctx.lineWidth = 5;

/// define shadow, KEY: offset X shadow (or y if prefered=
ctx.shadowOffsetX = offset;
ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.shadowBlur = 16;

/// draw the shape
ctx.stroke();

/// translate back, or use save/restore
ctx.translate(offset, 0);
```

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/y9ujV/)**